# Should I declare a variable inside a function or outside?

Tags: javascript, function, var

I'm really bad a javascript please don't get me wrong if you find this question dumb;
if I have two variables, should I have declared them inside or outside the function?

like this

```
var Num = document.querySelector("#Fnumber");
var Num2 = document.querySelector("#Secnumber");
function Multiply(){
alert(Num.value + Num2.value)
}

//or declaring variable inside a function like this ?

function Multiply(){
var Num = document.querySelector("#Fnumber").value;
var Num2 = document.querySelector("#Secnumber").value;
alert(Num + Num2)
}
```

and am I pasting the value Property correct on both examples ?

Comment: Depends on how you have everything else set up.  Encapsulation is good for reuse.  The issue is that each time it is called (if in a function) it would need to redetermine what NUM and NUM2 are which takes N time.  But usually i define the inputs as private properties of a class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are valid, you just have to be aware of the different scope the variables will be in. In the first example, the variables will be available outside of the function Multiply, they could be modified by other functions. In the second example, they are only available inside the Multiply function. When choosing where to declare your variables, you should ask yourself where you need to be able to use them, whether you are polluting the global scope, and how much of a performance hit are you taking when you declare them.

Comment: All sensible advice IMHO. I'd just add that also you have to consider whether the value of each variable needs to persist beyond the lifetime of the function, or whether it should be reset each time the function runs. If it's declared inside the function, then it resets each time

Answer (score 5):

I think declaring them outside is better because when you declare them inside you are selecting the inputs every time you run the function `Multiply()`. In the case of two inputs it will not effect the performance but in case of many elements it will definitely affect the performance.

But when you declare the elements outside you need to just access their `value`.

This also depends upon the importance of the elements `Num` and `Num2`. If the whole app uses them alot and they are used in other functions too then the variables should be declared outside

Answer (score 0):

This is good if you are using only in one function this variable value.

```
function Multiply(){
var Num = document.querySelector("#Fnumber").value;
var Num2 = document.querySelector("#Secnumber").value;
alert(Num + Num2)
}
```